# Skinning Cocoa controls

Tags: cocoa

Is there any easy way of creating a OS X Cocoa application with skinned controls? For example, if I wanted to create a slider control with a green heart shaped button, would I need to re-implement the whole slider functionality, or is there an easier way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can customize [controls and cells](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ControlCell/ControlCell.html) and do your own [drawing](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html). That's about your only option for "skinning" standard controls.